# How to get around StoreProblemError with RevenueCat and Flutter?

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

I have setup my subscription in the Google Play Console and also set it up with the same ID in RevenueCat but whenever I attempt to actually make the purchase I get

````
W/[Purchases] - INFO( 8853): Error updating purchases. DebugMessage: Service connection is disconnected.. ErrorCode: SERVICE_DISCONNECTED.
E/[Purchases] - ERROR( 8853): There was a problem with the Play Store. | Error updating purchases. DebugMessage: Service connection is disconnected.. ErrorCode: SERVICE_DISCONNECTED.
W/[Purchases] - INFO( 8853): Failed to launch billing intent. DebugMessage: Service connection is disconnected.. ErrorCode: SERVICE_DISCONNECTED.
I/flutter ( 8853): ERROR: PlatformException(2, There was a problem with the Play Store., {code: 2, message: There was a problem with the Play Store., readableErrorCode: StoreProblemError, readable_error_code: StoreProblemError, underlyingErrorMessage: Error updating purchases. DebugMessage: Service connection is disconnected.. ErrorCode: SERVICE_DISCONNECTED., userCancelled: false})
E/flutter ( 8853): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: There was a problem with the Play Store.```
````

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I ran into the exact same thing with Android Studio.

Comment: No luck from me... Have you made any progress?

Comment: Hey there, I finally found out  what was going on. Someone from RC helped me. it seems it was affecting someone else too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63031839/revenuecat-service-connection-is-disconnected?noredirect=1#comment111483973_63031839

Answer (score 0):

I've identified the scenario that triggers the error in Android Kotlin, and it can be replicated when users encounter the following message: S**toreProblemError, There was a problem with the store., Error updating purchases. DebugMessage: Server error, please try again.. ErrorCode: ERROR**. This occurs when a user has previously cancelled a subscription and attempts to purchase it again.

The recommended solution is to ask the user to either resubscribe to the app or remove the subscription from the Play Store by navigating to Profile -> Payments and subscriptions -> App_subscription.

[image]