# RevenueCat - Service connection is disconnected

Tags: google-play-services, android-billing, revenuecat

I am getting the error "SERVICE_DISCONNECTED" on Android Studio when I try to make a purchase with RevenueCat. I've searched everywhere but nothing has worked so far.
I followed their quickstart guide and double checked everything but I can't get purchases to work.

The following is the full log of the error when I try to purchase:

```
W/BillingClient: Exception while launching billing flow: ; for sku: mysku; try to reconnect
W/[Purchases] - INFO: Error updating purchases. DebugMessage: Service connection is disconnected.. ErrorCode: SERVICE_DISCONNECTED.
E/[Purchases] - ERROR: There was a problem with the Play Store. | Error updating purchases. DebugMessage: Service connection is disconnected.. ErrorCode: SERVICE_DISCONNECTED.
W/[Purchases] - INFO: Failed to launch billing intent. DebugMessage: Service connection is disconnected.. ErrorCode: SERVICE_DISCONNECTED.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Noah-1, are you using Flutter? We got a similar report this week https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-flutter/issues/87. I wonder if there's something wrong with our support for the older Android API

Comment: Hey @Cesar. I am using Android Studio 4.0.1 and Kotlin. Here is someone else with the same issue: https://docs.revenuecat.com/discuss/5f121019af2ab9032a4b633a

Comment: That's the same person that opened the issue in Flutter. The solution for Flutter was related to the context that was passed when initializing the SDK. How are you calling `purchasePackage`/`purchaseProduct`? Make sure the first parameter you are passing to those functions is an activity context. https://sdk.revenuecat.com/android/purchases/com.revenuecat.purchases/-purchases/purchase-package.html

Comment: Wow. That seems to be exactly the issue here. I was calling the purchase function from an adapter exactly as it is written on the Quickstart guide but if I call it from the same activity, it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Will you able the resolve this problem? I am facing the same issue